# REST API Post request - Request Error

Tags: wcf, rest, wcf-data-services

[image]I have a REST API call that uses post method. The WCF Service inturn saves the input string to the database. Here is my WCF Contract

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "/xxxx")]
int xxxx(string username);
```

When I use DHC client on chrome to test , it displays a bad request error.  The json data send to the server is of the form {"username": test123}
Pls find the image below

Is the format of the data sent to server incorrect ? Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

The contract should be marked with following WebInvoke attributes -
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "/xxxx")]